# How to perform join operation on two schema RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have two SchemaRDD's and I want to perform join operation on them (same like SQL join). 
please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually **do** a SQL join if you register the two SchemaRDDs as tables. While the following example uses case classes the technique doesn't depend on them:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
case class Score(name: String, score: Int)
case class Age(name: String, age: Int)
val scores = sc.textFile("scores.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(s => Score(s(0),s(1).trim.toInt))
val ages = sc.textFile("ages.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(s => Age(s(0),s(1).trim.toInt))
scores.registerAsTable("scores")
ages.registerAsTable("ages")
val joined = sqlContext.sql("""
    SELECT a.name, a.age, s.score
    FROM ages a JOIN scores s
    ON a.name = s.name""")
joined.collect().foreach(println)
```

Another approach, that doesn't require registration, is to use the language-integrated syntax (one suspects there is a way to streamline this):

```
val scoresAliased = scores.as('s)
val agesAliased = ages.as('a)
val joined = 
  scoresAliased.join(agesAliased, Inner, Some("s.name".attr === "a.name".attr))
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations)

> join(otherDataset, [numTasks])    When called on datasets of type (K, V)
>   and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of
>   elements for each key. Outer joins are also supported through
>   leftOuterJoin and rightOuterJoin.

You would want to run your schemaRDDs through a map transformation to put them in the `(K,V)` form: `K` is the key you want to join on, and `V` can just be the entire row object. E.g.

```
val a = ...
val b = ...
val bWithKey = b.map(v => (v.key, v))
val joined = a.map(v => (v.key, v)).join(bWithKey)
```